# React JS printing data inside a nested map function in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested-loops, jsx

I am trying to print data inside a nested map function. For some reason it does not print anything. here is what I have:

```
  {dataFormat.protein_questions.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={_.uniqueId()} className="item">
         <div className="inline fields">
           <Field
              onChange={handleChange}
              name={`protein_question[${index}].units_of_measurement`}
              component="select"
              className="ui dropdown2"
              required>

                 {item.typing_methods.map((method, methodIndex) => {
                    method.unitsOfMeasurement.map((unit, unitIndex) => (
                       <option value={unit.title}>{unit.title}</option>
                    ));
                 })}

          </Field>
         </div>
       </div>
  ))}
```

The options are not printing any data inside the select for some reason. When I console log the data inside the nested loop it shows fine. Anyone know why this is happening?

By the way this is inside my render function in a JSX view file.

Comment: but you are not returing anything from the `item.typeing_methods.map`, so I am not sure what you are expecting

Comment: I think you need to add return statement every where

Comment: @DhavalRajani no, he is doing it correctly in the other map statements, not that they start with `(` and not `{`, the first will implicitely return the statement, the second expects a return

Comment: Just out of curiosity, was it one of you two who voted to close this question?

Comment: @user3574492 yeah, I did, as for me this is a offtopic as a it is a small I oversight on your part

Comment: @Icepickle Off topic? Please explain how exactly? How does this against the SO question policy? A small oversight with big effects, this is the point of SO right? To ask programming questions that you can't solve yourself and it hopefully benefits other people.

Comment: @user3574492 forgetting a `return` statement is for me a typo, this is one of the reasons that are available to close the topic with. On the other side, if you wouldn't have added the curly brackets it would also have worked, in so far, I don't think it would help future users, but I might ofcourse be alone in my opinion :). Furthermore, you do it correct in the other maps, which points me even more to the typo off-topic

Comment: @Icepickle It's clearly not a typo did I misspell something or did I not include a statement that I did not know about? Clearly the latter. I think you are alone in your opinion. The curly brackets were intended because I won't be able to add any JS IF statements after the first map if I used the normal brackets. The question is perfectly fine, quit being a nuisance and think before you click that close button.

Comment: @user3574492 Opinions are opinions, they differ person to person, not only that, but I gave you the correct answer in my first comment already as it was clearly an oversight. I didn't down-vote the question, I just voted to close it for the reason provided, which is perfectly in my right to do so. And you obviously knew the statement cause you do it in the other cases, and you pointed out in the comment on the answer that you forgot something. I don't see what's the big deal of getting a close vote, if no one else votes, it will age away

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you forgot `return` before `method.unitsOfMeasurement...`:

```
{item.typing_methods.map((method, methodIndex) => {
  return method.unitsOfMeasurement.map((unit, unitIndex) => (
    <option value={unit.title}>{unit.title}</option>
  ));
})}
```

Comment: Genius! I forgot you had to always return something in the main loop. I'll accept when it lets me.